# Подключения библиотеки не используя Composer

Tags: php, composer

https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php

Нужно использовать данную библотеку, но установить используя Composer возможности нет. 
Скачал библиотеку, подключил в свой php файл

```
require_once("./src/Client.php");
require_once("./src/Configuration.php");
```

Но при создании объекта

```
$configuration = Configuration::oauth($accessToken);
```

выдает ошибку что такого класса нет.

Comment: `use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;` вангую, что нужно сделать как там написано и всё заработает. А лучше подключить где-нибудь composer, скачать и закинуть туда, где его нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забываете про `namespace`

```
$configuration = Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration::oauth($accessToken);
```

или

```
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
$configuration = Configuration::oauth($accessToken);
```

Comment: куда это вписывать? если объясняете, то пожалуйста объясняйте, чтоб новичкам понятно было. нигде никто нормально объяснить не может

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Дополнительно вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/388620)

Comment: @user346348, что именно не понятно куда вписывать? Создайте вопрос что бы можно было уведить в чем именно у вас проблема